# How to use axios.request(config) in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to use `Axios` in my vue.js project and I want to send `HTTP` requests. 
I read [Axios socumentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#instance-methods) in github and checked lots of samples on the web but I couldn't find my answer. 
I want to define a config file and read requests path from it and call it with Axios. There are lots of APIs that I need to call and prefer to keep it in a separate file. I do not want to use `axios.get` or `axios.post` instead of that prefer to use this style:

```
// in my APIs file 
export default {
  GetAll: {
    method: 'get',
    url: '/Book/GetAll'
  },
  GetById: {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'Book/GetById/{id}'
  },
  Add: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'Book/Add'
  }
}
```

```
// Axios instantiation 
import Axios from 'axios'

Vue.use({
  Axios
})

const Server = Axios.create({
  baseURL: myUrl
})

export default Server
```

```
// in my component

import Server from './server'
import Api from './api'

export default {
  async mounted() {
    var list = (await Server.request(Api.GetAll)).data

    var book = (await Server.request(Api.GetById)).data
  }
}
```

In the component I can get the list but I don't know how I can call `GetById` API.

Comment: I assume what you're asking is how to implement the relevant substitution in `'Book/GetById/{id}'`? Ignoring the implementation details for a second, how would you like the call from the component to look? How would you expect other things to work, like passing parameters or body data along with the request? It feels like you've picked an architecture before considering the requirements. If you can sketch out what the calls should look like for all of these relevant considerations then perhaps someone can suggest a way of implementing it.

Comment: @skirtle, Thank you for comment. I was using `vue resource` before and it was much easier to send the requests but it seems `vue resource` is retired now. I expect something to send get request with parameter `id` like `Book/GetById/1` or for post request, put it in request body. I hope this can help.

Comment: I don't think that really answers my questions. I want to know what you want the code in the component to look like. You've made some design decisions already but you've left major gaps in the design. In its present form your question is too broad to provide an answer.

Comment: @skirtle I want to use it like `await Server.request(Api.GetAll)` or `await Server.request(Api.GetById, 2)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to wrap all rest api calls like this:

```
class RestApi {
    constructor() {
        this.client = axios.create({
            baseURL: 'base-url-here'
        });
    }

    async get(url, params = {}) {
        return this.client.request({
            type: 'get',
            url: url,
            params: params
        })
    }

    async post(url, data = {}) {
        return this.client.request({
            type: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: data
        })
    }

    async getById(id) {
        return this.get(`Book/GetById/${id}`)
    }
}

const api = new RestApi();
const response = await api.getById(1);
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this case, the get request will change to `myUrl/GetById?id=1` instead of `myUrl/GetById/1`

Comment: Each method can control how to format url, and how to pass rest of the parameters, so in case of getById, url should be  /Book/GetById/1 without any query parameters.